# llvm find if a variable is used in the instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am new to llvm and i need to parse a bitcode for checking a variable is used in some specific type of instruction.
so i need to do two things. 1) check if a instruction if of some specific type 
2) see if a variable is used in the given instruction

Any help or clue in this direction? thanks in advance !

Comment: Just want to confirm that you are parsing a `*.bc` file vs. a `*.ll` file?

Comment: i am parsing a bc file.

Comment: Have you read through http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html#enter-subblock-encoding? The document also notes `llvm-bcanalyzer` as potentially useful to understanding the format.